# First page blank when multiple pages rendered?

Tags: python, django, pisa

I use pisa for print from html to pdf. And I have a problem. 
if amount of data few, than print in first page. if amount of data more, than he print in next page, but first page is empty. 
What do you think about it?
Please help me

```
table {
        -pdf-keep-with-next: true;
    }

    @page {
        size: letter portrait;
        margin-right: 30pt;
        margin-left: 30pt;
    }

    @frame content_frame {
        left: 50pt;
        width: 512pt;
        top: 50pt;
        height: 692pt;
    }



context = Context(context_dict)
        html = template.render(context)
        result = StringIO.StringIO()
        pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode("UTF-8"), result, encoding='UTF-8', link_callback=self.fetch_resources)
        response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report-%s-%s.pdf' % (start_date, end_date)
        RequestContext(request)

<tbody>
     <tr class="text-center">
        <td>{% trans "Date" %}</td>
        <td class="padding-top-5">
            <p class="text-center"> {% trans "Journal" %} </p>
            <p style="margin: 0 5pt;">{% trans "history, status, diagnosis and treatment for the treatment of recurrent disease" %}</p>
        </td>
        <td>{% trans "Doctor" %}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for reception in receptions %}
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="width: 30%; vertical-align: top">
                <p class="separator">&nbsp;</p>
                {{ reception.date_created|date:"d F Y" }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="padding: 5px">
                    {% if reception.result|length_is:0 or reception.result == None %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ reception.result|linebreaks }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

            <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 30%">
                <p class="separator">&nbsp;</p>
                &nbsp;{{ reception.doctor.doctor_name }}
            </td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post some code please, otherwise your question is impossible to answer and will be closed.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23903081/edit) and add this code snippet there.

Comment: i resolved this problem. I deleted style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" from tag body, and add this style to tag td.